# Finite dense subset implies $X$ finite

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Suppose $E \subset X$ is a finite dense subset. Prove that $X$ must also be finite.

This is proven quite easily by showing that $\bar{E} = E$ since $E' = \emptyset$, so that $\bar{E} = X$.

However, to study for my analysis final, I've been trying to prove things in a bunch of different ways to really gain intuition. So, here's an attempt at an alternate proof.

Suppose $X$ is infinite. We will show that $E$ must also be infinite. Let $x_1 \in X$. Since $E \overset{dense}{\subset} X$, for $\epsilon >0$, there is $p_1 \in B_\epsilon (x_1)$, $p_1 \in E$. Now, take $x_2 \in X$. Either $x_2 \in B_\epsilon (x_1)$ or not. In any case, set $r_2 = \frac{1}{2} d(x_2,p_1)$. Then, $p_1 \notin B_{r_2} (x_2)$. But, since $E$ is dense, we must have $p_2 \in B_{r_2} (x_2)$. Inductively, take $x_k \in X$ so that either $x_k \in B_\epsilon(x_1)$ or $$x_k \in \bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1} B_{r_i} (x_i).$$ In either case, set $$r_k = \min\{d(x_k,p_1), \ldots, d(x_k,p_{k-1})\}$$
which exists for every $k$. Moreover, $p_j \notin B_{r_k}(x_k)$ for $j\leq k-1$. But, since $E$ is again dense, we must have $p_k \in B_{r_k}(x_k)$. Repeating this process, we see that $|E|$ must be at $\aleph_0$ if $|X|$ is at least $\aleph_0$. So, we must have $X$ finite if $E$ is a finite dense subset.

Is this a correct proof?

Comment: The proof is (absolutely) correct but you use (I think) the countable axiom of choice and you do it by contradiction. Here I assume that you are on the real numbers, on such sets every $\{x\}$ is closed so a finite union of such sets is closed as well and hence any finite set is closed. (it is a better argument than the one using the interior of the set, my opinion again). However coming with a carefull solution like this is indubitably a good training.